# KDE won't start for one user account on Fedora 25

Tags: linux, fedora, login, kde, mate

I am running Fedora 25 with stock KDE desktop.   I was toying around with Mate, and now, for some reason or other, I am unable to login to one specific account.

I have two accounts, user1 and user2.   I can log into User1 fine, no apparent issues.  However if I return to the login screen and attempt to log into user2, the system seems to just freeze.   After I type in the password for user2 and hit enter, the mouse cursor changes to an "X" and then the system becomes non-responsive.   I haven't been able to do anything other than a forced hard restart to get out of it.

If I login as user1 and then start up a vnc session for user2's account, I can log into the vnc session just fine and see a KDE/Plasma desktop.

I assume there's some startup script or something that isn't working properly, but I'm a little new to the environment so I have no idea what or where to go to see what's happening here.  I also imagine it had something to do with having installed Mate and then uninstalling it since that's when this issue began.

It's also possible that Mate was installed as root, and maybe this caused the problem?  But if so, why would user1 still be able to login without issue?

Any suggestions or education on how KDE starts would be appreciated.

Comment: "non-responsive" – Does this mean you cannot even do Ctrl+Alt+2 to get to tty2? Or can you? One time I had a similar problem with KDE in my Kubuntu. Logging in via tty2 and removing `~/.Xauthority` did help.